# Heston model (closed-form moments of returns)

Tags: finance-mathematics, heston

Are there closed form expressions for unconditional moments (first, second) for stock returns under Heston model? Most sources provide the moments for the variance process in Heston model, but not for the stock returns. Does this mean that first two moments of stock return distribution are not available in closed form for Heston model?

Comment: Hi, my last comment was wrong. What you can do: Using the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Moments) of the logarithmic stock price under the Heston model, calculate the first, second, third, ... derivative, and multiply by +i or -i according to the Wiki article. This is a bit tedious, but will yield closed solutions.